# How to map blob file "content" to an existing "content" field in an index based on blob metadata_storage_path property?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to create an index using **Azure SQL** and **Azure Blob** Data source. Blob container contains files in following formats **word, pdf, pptx, txt**, and etc.

[Click here for Index Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6o3n.png)

1. "ItemId" is the **Key** field in the index, data is pulled from **item** table in the db.
2. "DocumentList" is a collection which holds files metadata including file storage path.
3. "DocumentList" is derived from an SQL Json array column. Json column holds the files metadata against item.
4. Files are stored in blob and blob path is stored in the above json column under "DocumentLocation" property.

**Note:** Each row in db. can hold multiple files in the blob.

**Questions:**

1. How to map the blob "content" to the "Content" field under "DocumentList" field in the index using "DocumentLocation" as the basis for joining?
2. Can we define field mapping or output field mapping for above scenario. if it is possible, how to do that?
3. Any other approach to above scenario ?

*Any suggestions are much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

Using the current code snippet, make the name changes according to the requirement.

```
"fieldMappings": [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
    "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path"
  },
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
    "targetFieldName": "index_key",
    "mappingFunction": {
       "name": "base64Encode"
    }
  }
]
```

For better understanding, follow the procedure mentioned in the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings